# I cannot get my message box to appear at the correct instance (Beginner)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am programming a small app and I cannot get my message box to work at the correct time, and when it does come up, the label still updates.  It's driving me nuts!  The message box needs to appear with the days less than 19, and greater than 22. The two bottom errors do work correctly at least I do believe they did earlier (prior to me trying to get the other errors to work). Below is my code. I need the error mentioned above(message box) to appear when the number entered is less than 19 and greater than 22 btw.

Thank you :). This is in vb.net btw.

```
'Date: 3/21/2015
'Purpose: The application finds the amount of a monthly pau if you are paid on a penny or nickel a day for the first workday then the pay is doubled each workday.
'    Inexpereinced workers are paid a penny a day, experienced workers are paid a nickel. 


Option Explicit On


Public Class frmPennyOrNickelADay

    Const _cdecPenny As Decimal = 0.01D
    Const _cdecNickel As Decimal = 0.05D
    Const _cDecDoubledAmount As Decimal = 2D
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim decSalary As Decimal = 0
        Dim intDay As Integer
        Dim decPenny As Decimal = 0.01D
        Dim decNickel As Decimal = 0.05D
        Dim decDouble As Decimal = 2
        Dim intRunningTally As Integer
        Dim decMaxNumber As Decimal
        If IsNumeric(txtDaysWorkedUserEntry.Text) = True Then
            intDay = Convert.ToInt32(txtDaysWorkedUserEntry.Text)
            If intDay > 0 Then
                If radPenny.Checked = True Then
                    If intDay < 19 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Error", "input error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                        lblAmountEarnedResult.Text = ""

                    End If
                End If
                If radPenny.Checked = True Then
                    decSalary = decPenny

                ElseIf radNickel.Checked = True Then
                    decSalary = decNickel
                End If

                For intDay = 1 To intDay
                    If intDay = 1 Then
                        decSalary = decSalary
                    Else
                        decSalary *= decDouble
                    End If
                    intRunningTally += decSalary

                Next

                lblAmountEarnedResult.Text = decSalary.ToString("C2")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number greater than one", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK)


            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Letters are not an acceptible input within this application, please try again...enter a value greater than one.",
                            "Invalid Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        End If



    End Sub
```

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, where specifically does it fail?  Where does it behave differently than you expect, and what are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: When is the messagebox appearing? More details pls.

Comment: It appears fine...it just doesn't appear at the appropriate time.  For example, It appears, but still updates the lblAmountEarnedResult when it shouldn't since there is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exit your subroutine after the messagebox is shown, try using `Exit Sub`

```
If intDay < 19 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Error", "input error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    lblAmountEarnedResult.Text = ""
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!  Four days on this same part and in a matter of minutes you guys had it solved lol.   You're the best!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
If intDay < 19 Then
```

To

```
If (intDay < 19 or intDay >22) then
```

Comment: Also change.


    If intDay > 0 Then


To

    If (If (intDay < 19 or intDay >22) then